# How to change the button layout when the Lottie Animation ends in angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, lottie

One of the requirements of our application is to use `Lottie` to add animation for the onboarding part of the app. The scenario will be, if the Lottie animation has ended, the *Skip to Homepage* button should change to the *Home* button. I am having a hard time on how I will implement it with my app. I've been stuck here for almost a week but still, I can't apply to my app. I am quite confused if I applied it correctly. Hope you can help me. I will be adding my codes below for reference. Thank you

**.ts**

```
 // LOTTIE
   animationCreated(animationItem: AnimationItem): void {
   this.animationItem = animationItem;
   this.animationItem.autoplay = true;
   this.animationItem.loop = false;
    if (this.animationItem.loop === false) {
     this.onLoopComplete();
     this.showHomeButton = true;
   }
 }

  onLoopComplete(): void {
     this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
     this.animationItem.addEventListener('loopComplete', () => {});
     console.log(
       this.animationItem.addEventListener('loopComplete', () => {})
     );
   });
 }
```

**.html**

```
<div class="demo">
        <ng-lottie
          *ngIf="shown"
          containerClass="centerLottie"
          width="520px"
          height="420px"
          [options]="options"
          (animationCreated)="animationCreated($event)"
        ></ng-lottie>
      </div>   

   <ion-row>
     <ion-col size="4"></ion-col>
     <ion-col size="4">
     <div class="ion-text-center ion-no-padding" *ngIf="this.pageInddex_d==1">
      <ion-button  *ngIf="!showHomeButton" fill="clear" routerLink="/home" size="large" shape="round" color="primary">
      Skip to homepage
      </ion-button>
    <ion-button  *ngIf="showHomeButton" expand="full" routerLink="/home" size="large" shape="round" color="primary">
        Home
      </ion-button>
     </div>
```